How to request an update for carrier_list.textpb at android.googlesource.com
The carrier_list.textpb presented on this link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/master/assets/latest_carrier_id/carrier_list.textpb#4295 has wrong information for carrier_name for 2 carrier_id:
carrier_id {
 canonical_id: 1608
  **carrier_name: "Cosmofon"**
  carrier_attribute {
  mccmnc_tuple: "29402"
  }
}
carrier_id {
  canonical_id: 1609
  **carrier_name: "Nov Operator"**
  carrier_attribute {
  mccmnc_tuple: "29403"
  }
}

This results with wrong information when using the source for android internet speed test application.
What options do I have to change this source code?
